# Invert regex match across lines

Tags: regex

How would you invert this expression to match everything BUT the contents between the `<!-- LIST -->` and `<!-- /LIST -->` tags?

```
((?s)<!-- LIST -->.*?<!-- /LIST -->)
```

Meaning I'd like to remove everything before `<!-- LIST -->` and after `<!-- /LIST -->`

Comment: This is not a good place to be using regular expressions, because a tagged language isn't regular.

Comment: @maexls: tell me if the provided solution works as expected for you or if it's needed to refine it.

Comment: @GsusRecovery: that did work, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you have used already matches the section between the two tags, you have to simply add the prior and following sections and use the backreference to replace all the contents with the saved group (usually the slash `/` is to escape also).

This is a generic regex code:

```
s/(?s).*(<!-- LIST -->.*?<!-- \/LIST -->).*/\1/
```

Implementation online [here](https://regex101.com/r/pS0uN0/1)